# how to exclude inner dictionary key inside a nested dictionary using a dict comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have this dictionary:

```
params = {'H': {'amt_thold_high': 0.0, 'amt_thold_restricted': 0.0, 'num_par': 2.0, 'version': 2.1},
          'M': {'amt_thold_high': 0.0, 'amt_thold_restricted': 0.0, 'num_par': 2.0},
          'L': {'amt_thold_high': 0.0, 'amt_thold_restricted': 0.0, 'num_par': 2.0}}
```

I want to return the exact same dictionary excluding the inner k `version` from first outer key `H`.

This is what i have come with so far:

```
{outer_k:outer_v for outer_k,outer_v in params.items() for inner_k, inner_v in outer_v.items() if inner_k != 'version'}
```

And this is the result i'm getting:

```
{'H': {'amt_thold_high': 0.0,
  'amt_thold_restricted': 0.0,
  'num_par': 2.0,
  'version': 2.1},
 'M': {'amt_thold_high': 0.0, 'amt_thold_restricted': 0.0, 'num_par': 2.0},
 'L': {'amt_thold_high': 0.0, 'amt_thold_restricted': 0.0, 'num_par': 2.0}}
```

Why my solution is not working and how can i achieve my goal using a dict comprehension?

Comment: Maybe even faster: for k, v in params.items():
    if v.get('version'):
        v.pop('version')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to nest the comprehensions

```
{outer_k: {inner_k: inner_v 
           for inner_k, inner_v in outer_v.items() if inner_k != 'version'} 
 for outer_k, outer_v in params.items()}
```

and apply the conditional to the inner `dict`.

Comment: Thank you very  much!! i didn't think about that way. That's smart :)

Comment: Yeah, you repeated the *same* outer_k, outer_v items for every outer/inner combo (except the filtered one). So you'd catch all inner keys eventually.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation so much, i knew i was doing something wrong but i couldn't figure out where the error was